# Policy on reasked questions and bounties

Tags: discussion

I posted a [Movie Identification on Sci-Fi exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73379/23386) a few months ago.  I put a bounty on it, but just before it expired, I still didn't have the correct answer. I wanted the bounty to go to the answer that I thought was the closest so I accepted it even though it was incorrect.

Just recently I [reposted the question on Movies exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34075/49) and I got the right answer!  But it was deleted afterward.  I understand where the moderator was coming from when he deleted the post since they are the same question but he deleted the new one with the right answer.

What is the policy on these sorts of issues?

Also why is there is a time limit on a bounty?  And why does the bounty automatically go to the answer with the most votes?  This was the primary reason I accepted an incorrect answer on my first post.  Because I was unhappy with the answer that had the most votes.

Comment: Time limits on bounties because of the massively elevated visibility, if they never expired, it would defeat the purpose since you'd just have two long lists of questions (one with bounties and one without).

Comment: Regarding the questions, in an ideal world from the point of view of preserving content, the SF&F question would be deleted and we'd keep the MTV one, but it's unlikely that a highly voted SF&F question would get deleted. Maybe since the question posted on MTV actually contained the right answer an exception could be made, but then you're clearly in moderator territory, wait for somebody with a diamond to respond.

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted  it if it wasn't the correct answer. You know that you as the bounty giver have all the control to which question you award it, there's no need to use the automatic awarding feature and no need to accept a wrong answer, let alone give it a bounty.

Comment: @Flyk Well, the proper way to go would probably have been to flag the older question for migration. And that would have to be done, since the asker always has the last word about migration if it's on-topic on both sites.

Comment: I was unaware that I could award the bounty without accepting it as the correct answer.  I think my issues have been resolved.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to meta.

You had asked a question on another StackExchange and that got multiple answers, from which you even **accepted one as the correct answer**. Then you reposted the exact same question on another site. This is discouraged behaviour in the first place. **Cross-posting identical questions by the same user is not something to be done**. If a question doesn't seem to get any satisfactory answers and you want to reask it on another site, you can flag it for migration and that migration wish should be heeded by the moderators on the source site if the question is on-topic on the target site. But since the question actually was 100% solved on the other site I saw no use in keeping the cross-post at all.

If you say your older question was not adequately answered and the acceptance was a mistake, then the very first thing to do is to **unaccept that incorrect answer** to clarify to everyone that the question is *not* solved yet.

Then *if* you still want it to move to another site, you should **flag the question with a custom moderator flag, saying that you want it migrated to the other site**. And then we can even merge it with that (currently deleted) reposted question so that you get the supposedly right answer from the newer question and can properly accept it.

---

As to your question about bounties. That is simply the mechanism that comes into play when you do not award the bounty manually. However, **nothing stops you from just awarding the bounty manually** to the question which you think deserves it best.

Comment: Can I get the answer from MTV merged with the original question on Sci Fi?

Comment: @bburk707 You mean you want to keep the SciFi question but give it the answer you got here? You can either do that by just answering it yourself with the correct answer. The hard and more formal way would probably be to migrate the movies question over there and then close it as duplicate of the existing one and then have the moderators merge it into the existing one. In this case the answer keeps to be given by the user who answered it here. I can talk with the SciFi mods about that. I'll tell you if this won't work, in which case you can just answer it yourself.

Comment: @bburk707 Done, you can now accept the answer on the original SciFi question.

Comment: Awesome thank you